# Setting WPF background Opacity programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, opacity

I'm working on application which creates a new wpf border component for each row in a database. This means I've got to style the border component in C# rather than XAML (as far as I'm aware). The styling is all good so far apart from trying to set the background opacity.

```
motherboards.Add(new Border());
Border moboBorder = motherboards[i];
moboBorder.Width = 150;
moboBorder.Height = 150;
moboBorder.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
moboBorder.Background = Brushes.White;
moboBorder.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(10);
moboBorder.Margin = new Thickness(5);
moboBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
```

You can adjust the background opacity in XAML like so

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" Height="100" Width="100">
    <Border.BorderBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.7"/>
    </Border.BorderBrush>
</Border>
```

But as I've said I'm creating the component in C# rather than XAML. I guess this is how you set the value in c#

```
moboBorder.Background.Opacity = //Value
```

However, I can't figure out what kind of value it takes, not just a straight up number, nothing from brushes than I can see and nothing like = new Opacity()

I've tried googling around but everything is about setting the opacity for the whole element rather than just the background of it.

Comment: Doesn't it take a `double`, between `0.0` and `1.0`?

Comment: @GeoffJames that's what I thought but no it says that it's read only: https://i.imgur.com/VEkaW9I.png

Comment: @nomicron You can't set the opacity property on a brush once it's in use. You can create a new Brush though: `Background = new SolidColorBrush(((SolidColorBrush)Background).Color) { Opacity = 0.5 };`

Comment: So you can't set it because it's `readonly`. That's because you're trying to set the `Opacity` of a `Brush. You need to set the `Background` itself with a `Brush` with an `Opacity` of your desire

Comment: For any future reader (and potential comment upvoter), please note that it's wrong to say that you "can't set the opacity property on a brush once it's in use". You can very well do that, provided that the Brush is not frozen. The members of the Brushes class are frozen, and can therefore not be changed (regardless whether they are in use or not).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `double` is certainly a "straight up number"; hover the mouse over the property to see the data type.

The problem (thanks, Clemens) is that you're trying to set the opacity of `Brushes.Black`, which is a system object and you've got no business doing that.

But you can set the `Opacity` of a `SolidColorBrush` that you create yourself.

To create a new semi-opaque white brush:

```
x.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White) { Opacity = 0.5 };
```

See Geoff's answer for how to create a color from an RGB triplet (or ARGB quad) instead of named colors.

Or just keep the existing brush, *if* you're confident that you didn't get it from `Brushes`.

```
Background.Opacity = 0.5;
```

If you did this, you got it from `System.Brushes`:

```
<Window
    Background="DeepSkyBlue"
    ...
```

If you did this, you didn't:

```
<Window.Background><SolidColorBrush Color="DeepSkyBlue" /></Window.Background>
```

That DeepSkyBlue is `Colors.DeepSkyBlue`; you're creating a new brush with that color.

You should be doing all of this in XAML with bindings instead of creating WPF controls in C#. You'll shoot your eye out, kid.

But it's your eye.

Comment: Totally agree with your suggestion of using bindings. MVVM all the way :o)

Comment: It's not true that "you can't set the Opacity of a Brush once it's in use". You just can't change the Opacity of the members of the Brushes class (as these are readonly). However, if you assign `Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)` to an element, you can easily later set `Background.Opacity = 0.5`. Both answers should be edited.

Comment: So finally there is no need to create and assign a *new* SolidColorBrush, just to set its Opacity. See my answer.

Comment: @Clemens - it's late, and I could be being really dumb, but isn't your comment contradictory to your own answer (about assigning a new SolidColorBrush)?

Comment: @GeoffJames No, I just do `x.Background.Opacity = 0.5;` instead of `x.Background = new SolidColorBrush(((SolidColorBrush)x.Background).Color) { Opacity = 0.5 };`. Of course after assigning it *once*, obviously.

Comment: But, you're still having to set `x` to a `new SolidColorBrush` (so as not to use a shared one), *before* setting its `Opacity`, right?

Comment: @GeoffJames Sure, but only once. Your answers both suggest you'd have to do it each time you change the Opacity.

Comment: @Clemens - I've probably taken your comment out of context and been a bit subjective, sorry. Far too often I see members of SO trolling all over others' answers for "see my answer" comments. I agree it's very constructive and adds good value to point these things out. I've deleted my stupid-ass comment, now, so as not to draw away from the point of the answers.

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent of the XAML

```
<Border.BorderBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.7"/>
</Border.BorderBrush>
```

in code behind would be

```
moboBorder.Background = new SolidColorBrush
{
    Color = Colors.Black,
    Opacity = 0.7
};
```

In contrast to the predefined Brushes in the `Brushes` class (which are [frozen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable.isfrozen(v=vs.110).aspx)), the above SolidColorBrush can be changed at any time later, like

```
moboBorder.Background.Opacity = 0.5;
```

Answer (score 2):

*As @Clemens kindly pointed out in the comments:*

You can't set the `Opacity` of the system's shared brushes directly.

You will need to use a non-shared `SolidColorBrush`, and then you will be able to set the `Opacity` of that.

You will be able to change the `Opacity` from any point in the code, from thereon-in.

E.g.:

```
moboBorder.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0))
                        {
                            Opacity = 0.5 // or whatever opacity between
                                          //  0.0 (0%) and 1.0 (100%)
                        };
```

Or

```
moboBorder.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0));
moboBorder.Background.Opacity = 0.5;
```

---

Similar the above example, you could also set the alpha (the opacity) if you're using RGB.

You can use the `Color.FromArgb()` static method, instead:

```
moboBorder.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0.5, 255, 0, 0));
```

Just use a double between `0.0` and `1.0` (as before), as your first argument to the method.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not true that "you can't set the Opacity of a Brush once it's in use". You just can't change the Opacity of the members of the Brushes class (as these are readonly). However, if you assign `Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)` to an element, you can easily later set `Background.Opacity = 0.5`. Both answers should be edited.

Comment: Good point, @Clemens - absolutely right! Updated my answer to clarify this to do with the shared brushes. Thanks!